# Jenkins build environment variables - Where can I use them?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I wonder where I can use build environment variables in the job configuration.

For example:

- At the "Source Code Management" I can use them.
- At the "Trigger/call builds on other projects" sections "Predefined parameters" I can't use them, because they aren't resolved.

I don't find any scheme behind this. Is this depending on the plugin behind the build configuration section? (Git Plugin etc.)

I have one Job doing some stuff and generating a value within a groovy system script that is injected in the build environment.

```
def pa = new ParametersAction([
    new StringParameterValue(key, value)
])
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)
```

This value is needed as a build parameter of the called next build in the chain and used in this build job as the branch to be checked out.

But I don't know how to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

You could make both those builds run on the same slave and and set the env variables on the slave in the first build. This env var then can be used by the downstream builds.